# EHCache configuration in WebApplication

Tags: java, grails, ehcache

I have written the below code for getting the cacheManager object

```
public class EHCacheUtil implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static CacheManager cacheMgr = null;

    private static Ehcache getCache(String cacheName) throws Exception{
        if(cacheMgr == null){
            File file = new File("F:\\ProjectWorkSpace\\src\\java\\ehcache.xml");

                // We could use an environment or a VM variable
                cacheMgr = CacheManager.create(new FileInputStream(file));
                System.out.println("cacheMgr.cacheExists(cacheName)"+cacheMgr.cacheExists(cacheName));
        }

        Ehcache cache = null;
        if(cacheMgr!=null){
                //cache = cacheMgr.addCacheIfAbsent(name);
                cache = cacheMgr.getEhcache(cacheName);
        }

        return cache;
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.sf.net/ehcache.xsd">

<diskStore path="G:\EHCacheTempMemory" />

<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true" timeToIdleSeconds="10" timeToLiveSeconds="20" diskPersistent="true" />

<cache name="myCache1"
maxElementsInMemory="500000"
maxElementsOnDisk="500000"
eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true"
timeToIdleSeconds="864000"
timeToLiveSeconds="8640000"
diskPersistent="true"
diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="8640000"
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />



</ehcache>
```

SOP is printing true for stand alone application but not for web application. 
can some one explain the issue?

Comment: do you have cluster environment

Comment: Does your web application have access to the same file as your stand-alone application has?

Comment: http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/grails

Comment: i understood that in my web application i have added the EHCache jars externally but already i am using Hibernate plugin  which is internally using EHCache libraries so i got conflict problems. Thanks for above suggestions.